# Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\CMS\ProjectCredentialCpanelController::edit() must be an instance using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to edit but unfortunately i am facing error please help me how to fix that thanks.
please check error
https://flareapp.io/share/dmk2jl53

Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\CMS\ProjectCredentialCpanelController::edit() must be an instance of App\ProjectCredentialCpanel, string given

**controller**

```
public function edit(ProjectCredentialCpanel $projectcredentialcpanel,$projectId)
    {
        $data = [
            'project' => $projectId,
            'isEdit' => true,
        ];

        return view('cms.credential.cpanel.add-cpanel', $data);
    }
```

**route**

```
Route::get('project/credential/{projectId}/cpanel/{projectcredentialcpanel}/edit', 'ProjectCredentialCpanelController@edit')->name('project.cpanel.edit');
```

Comment: what is parameter name in route?

Comment: did you change edit function  param ? Also please share which version is this ?

Comment: please check route parameter name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for route model binding the name of model you want to bind(variable) should match URI segment.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#implicit-binding .

so it will be:

```php
public function edit($projectId, ProjectCredentialCpanel $projectcredentialcpanel)
{
    $data = [
        'project' => $projectId,
        'isEdit' => true,
    ];

    return view('cms.credential.cpanel.add-cpanel', $data);
}
```

Comment: thanks sir last error resolved but i am facing error on html form how can i resolve this.https://flareapp.io/share/Lm8BEA7v#F58

Comment: in route some changes happened in recent laravel updates so you have to explicit for parameter name in array passed in route helper mean: ``` route('project.cpanel.update',['projectcredentialcpanel' => $projectcredentialcpanel->id]) ``` or what i prefer is dont pass array just id or parameter needed like this: ``` route('project.cpanel.update',$projectcredentialcpanel->id) ```